# Xcode how to debug unrecognized selector sent to instance

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, debugging

Ok so as far as i can tell I'm getting the error when I'm calling a setter designed to fit the view into it's correct box.

```
_parrentViewFrame = parrentViewFrame;
self.containerView.frame = _parrentViewFrame;
self.containerView.bounds = _parrentViewFrame;
[self.containerView layoutIfNeeded];
```

on the layoutIfNeeded i get this error

> *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSCFNumber length]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0xb000000000000343'

Now I've got similar code all over the app and it works just fine. I've put a symbolic break point at **-[NSObject(NSObject) doesNotRecognizeSelector:]**. but this doesn't really help. I still can't tell which object it's trying call length on.  containerView is a simple UIView.  The instance is always **0xb000000000000343**, not sure if thats significant but it seems like it would be.  How can I debug this problem?

Comment: Somewhere you assigned an `NSNumber` to an `NSString` property. Are you getting data from an array or dictionary? Perhaps a value you think is a string is really a number.

Comment: It'd probably be useful to look at the backtrace from the exception. That'd tell you which code is actually sending -length. It's not at all clear that the code you posted is even involved.

Comment: This exception `[__NSCFNumber length]` means that you have assigned `NSNumber` to `NSString`. And you can add one exception breakpoint for debug scheme in Xcode

Comment: Add "All Exceptions" and comment the result of "bt" in lldb command.

Answer (score 1):

One of two things might be going on:

1. As rmaddy pointed out, you may have assigned an `NSNumber` to a property that is not `NSNumber`. `NSString` seems like a likely candidate or an object that conforms to `UILayoutSupport`.
2. You might be overreleasing an object and an `NSNumber` is taking the place of that pointer, hence the bad selector call. If that is the case, you can turn on NSZombies, which will help you catch that overreleased object. Enable NSZombies in your scheme settings under Diagnostics.